# Filtering duplicate records using space and time overlap

Tags: r, point, distance, proximity, spatio-temporal-data

I have a dataset consisting of about 23,000 fire incidents obtained from years of fire brigade reports. The incidents have a lat, lon, and timestamp. The problem is that in the case when two (or more) fire brigades responded to the same incident, there are often duplicates where each brigade submitted its own report (each of which would have their own unique ID). I need to find a way to filter out these duplicate events in order to begin my analysis, but my initial attempt is not working. The attempt at identifying and removing duplicates is as follows:

Observations overlap in time if they are located within a specified temporal distance (e.g. 30 days) of one another.

Observations overlap in space if they are located within a specified spatial distance (e.g. 20 kilometers) of one another.

When records overlap in both time and space, I want to make a column that contains vectors with the ids of the observations that overlap with an observation. I have tried the R code **below**, but the run time is too poor for the solution to be applicable. Once the duplicates are identified, they must be filtered out.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(geosphere)

spat_proximity <- function(x, y, z) {
  
  return(which(map_dbl(y, ~ distGeo(., x)) <= z))}


temp_proximity <- function(x, y, z) {
    
  return(which(map_dbl(y, ~ abs(x - .)) <= z))}


test %>%
  mutate(overlaps = map2(map(place, ~ spat_proximity(., place, 20000)),
                         map(time, ~ temp_proximity(., time, 30)),
                         ~ intersect(.x, .y)))
```

How can I speed things up, or is there any alternate methods to filter the data? (ArcGIS, Python, etc. solutions are all welcome)

**Data**

```
structure(list(id = 1:42, time = structure(c(1478601762, 1475170279, 
1469770219, 1462441336, 1474739469, 1488216507, 1475203721, 1468705558, 
1481722718, 1485897197, 1488669576, 1501288618, 1510266595, 1516828588, 
1497048175, 1516546144, 1507576242, 1517654363, 1496070298, 1519765220, 
1507408104, 1532046710, 1542196446, 1534747170, 1533605231, 1521381844, 
1545389880, 1537988628, 1544304998, 1524842149, 1551051077, 1540822870, 
1579775599, 1580337175, 1551486497, 1554879837, 1568620434, 1568701543, 
1556387550, 1561253396, 1582925482, 1562166384), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), place = list(c(7.59729413351368, 52.6052275122351
), c(9.99728447956781, 53.43773657253), c(10.1114473929533, 53.1295890148866
), c(7.74115218835801, 53.555354690339), c(9.82895066827581, 
53.1009319396015), c(10.061107415855, 53.1908752763309), c(10.1134381934544, 
53.1450558612239), c(8.59001735546083, 53.1767797285482), c(6.43939168487555, 
52.5520931654252), c(8.38811111096636, 53.9043055557574), c(6.20061916537948, 
52.462037409576), c(8.66656282486832, 52.8269702466929), c(9.92127490588442, 
53.1240045666796), c(9.77810957468704, 53.1445777603789), c(10.0972382106036, 
53.1604265989175), c(10.0473952445094, 53.1698097395641), c(9.23773401919961, 
53.2120381900218), c(8.29524237837988, 52.822332696399), c(6.63690696797941, 
53.4436726627048), c(6.89839325296288, 53.947454203445), c(6.97064542834721, 
54.2487197094445), c(9.98865072631714, 53.4088944299342), c(9.94164401569524, 
53.1500576073959), c(9.64242996587752, 52.9285470044703), c(10.1026940185685, 
53.1635394335485), c(9.94874529044194, 53.2202512735354), c(8.8025526552284, 
53.2423093779114), c(7.93352467761445, 52.9129105531343), c(6.6418846001424, 
53.2459031608081), c(7.56102465003101, 53.5306444680171), c(7.36619114998468, 
53.748869508885), c(7.40993284414052, 54.5367797663042), c(9.90022663895919, 
53.3726361099083), c(9.41110555596208, 52.5001044709056), c(10.1151193231519, 
53.1539029361817), c(10.1064400828529, 53.1793449776572), c(9.94235711256256, 
53.2622041055899), c(9.44215997717822, 53.4799339987572), c(7.03832846889284, 
53.1986115213435), c(7.32755360272354, 53.416700338513), c(7.57828611098173, 
53.6107027769073), c(7.55411005022882, 54.1905803935834))), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share a small part of your dataset to better understand the problem?